# kubernetes install on ubuntu close connection in deploying

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

When I installing kubernetes on 3 ubuntu14.04 node,it going to deploying and suddenly stopped.
I had 3 nodes of this cluster:
172.25.2.31 ukub01
172.25.2.32 ukub02
172.25.2.33 ukub03
And I followed this document to install:
http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu.html

config-default.sh setting is:

```
export nodes=${nodes:-"root@ukub01 root@ukub02 root@ukub03 "}
role=${role:-"ai i i"}
export NUM_MINIONS=${NUM_MINIONS:-3}
export SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE=${SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE:-172.25.3.0/24}
export FLANNEL_NET=${FLANNEL_NET:-172.16.0.0/16}
```

deploying messages:

```
root@ukub01:/opt/kubernetes/cluster# KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh
... Starting cluster using provider: ubuntu
... calling verify-prereqs
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
... calling kube-up
Deploying master and node on machine ukub01

make-ca-cert.sh                                                                                                                                       100% 3398     3.3KB/s   00:00    
config-default.sh                                                                                                                                     100% 3232     3.2KB/s   00:00    
util.sh                                                                                                                                               100%   19KB  19.4KB/s   00:00    
kubelet.conf                                                                                                                                          100%  644     0.6KB/s   00:00    
kube-proxy.conf                                                                                                                                       100%  684     0.7KB/s   00:00    
flanneld.conf                                                                                                                                         100%  577     0.6KB/s   00:00    
kube-proxy                                                                                                                                            100% 2230     2.2KB/s   00:00    
kubelet                                                                                                                                               100% 2155     2.1KB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                                                                              100% 2159     2.1KB/s   00:00    
kube-controller-manager.conf                                                                                                                          100%  744     0.7KB/s   00:00    
kube-apiserver.conf                                                                                                                                   100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00    
kube-scheduler.conf                                                                                                                                   100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00    
etcd.conf                                                                                                                                             100%  664     0.7KB/s   00:00    
flanneld.conf                                                                                                                                         100%  568     0.6KB/s   00:00    
kube-controller-manager                                                                                                                               100% 2672     2.6KB/s   00:00    
etcd                                                                                                                                                  100% 2073     2.0KB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                                                                              100% 2159     2.1KB/s   00:00    
kube-apiserver                                                                                                                                        100% 2358     2.3KB/s   00:00    
kube-scheduler                                                                                                                                        100% 2360     2.3KB/s   00:00    
reconfDocker.sh                                                                                                                                       100% 1759     1.7KB/s   00:00    
kube-controller-manager                                                                                                                               100%   31MB  30.8MB/s   00:00    
etcd                                                                                                                                                  100% 6494KB   6.3MB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                                                                              100% 8695KB   8.5MB/s   00:00    
kube-apiserver                                                                                                                                        100%   37MB  36.9MB/s   00:00    
etcdctl                                                                                                                                               100% 6041KB   5.9MB/s   00:00    
kube-scheduler                                                                                                                                        100%   16MB  16.2MB/s   00:01    
kube-proxy                                                                                                                                            100%   16MB  16.1MB/s   00:01    
kubelet                                                                                                                                               100%   33MB  33.1MB/s   00:00    
flanneld                                                                                                                                              100% 8695KB   8.5MB/s   00:00    
Connection to ukub01 closed.
```

I had checked logs in /var/log/upstart .There are two files and I had not to find the reason occour the error.
flanneld.log:

```
I1010 14:47:40.249071 05088 main.go:292] Exiting...
```

systemd-logind.log

```
New session 3 of user root.
New session 4 of user root.
Removed session 4.
New session 5 of user root.
Removed session 3.
```

I think kubernetes/etcd/flannel can be installed  manually on ubuntu if there are option setting documents,And I installed etcd&flannel on the 3 nodes,but I still can't find the kubernetes part.

Can you help me about this error or tell me where can I find the kubernetes install and options setting document,please?

Comment: One more question,'SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE' setting should be the same IP range of the 3 nodes,or can be a random range?I should set it to 172.25.2.0/24 or like 10.11.1.0/24 or something is ok?

Comment: but it still doesn't work.because I had git and builded all the source from net,so I think it had no need to download anymore,include ca-cert.so why it hanged and how to check the step?I don't know.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: I saw very similar behavior when the easyrsa script gave an error while executing. I had to make sure the IP address in the script matched an IP on the machine, or the script failed.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're suffering a network issue (GWF mostly).
You could execute following command to verify it.

```
$ curl -L -O https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/easy-rsa/easy-rsa.tar.gz
```

Comment: Did this file should be apart of kubernetes ubuntu?If not,it only can prove I'm behind the GFW.And I think I had all of the needed file downloaded.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yeah it's included in make-ca-cert.sh